# How to declare, Two options for property declaration?

Tags: typescript

I have an interface like below

```
interface Student{
  Name: String;
  age: Number;
}
```

Instead of this I want to write like this

```
interface Student{
  Name: String;
  age | DOB: Number | Date;
}
```

ie the second property can either be `age` or `DOB`.
Is it possible? I am getting error for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
interface StudentWithAge{
  name: String;
  age: Number;
  DOB?: never;
}

interface StudentWithDOB {
  name: String;
  DOB: Date;
  age?: never;
}

type Student = StudentWithAge | StudentWithDOB;

const student1: Student = {
    name: 'Humayun Kabir',
    age: 18
}

const student2: Student = {
    name: 'Humayun Kabir',
    DOB: new Date()
}
```

Comment: This will allow `{name: "asdfd",  DOB: new Date(),  age: 42} `

Comment: Updated the answer. It should fix your issue. We have to use `never` to fix it.